# proper way of adding value to dynamically made input text tag

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<formInfo['elementCount'];i++){
    formElement = document.createElement('input');
    formElement.type = 'text';
    formElement.name = formInfo['elementName'][i];

    formElement.setAttribute("value",formInfo['elementValue'][i]); // <-this part

    console.log(formElement);

    newForm.appendChild(formElement);
}
```

The above code does not work if I use:

`formElement.value=formInfo['elementValue'][i];`

`console.log()` returns `<input type="text" name="abc">` (value attr is missing)

but it works if

`formElement.setAttribute("value",formInfo['elementValue'][i]);`

`console.log()` returns `<input type="text" name="abc" value="123">`

Why is the `formElement.value` method not working?

Checked this with both chrome and ff and both have the same results

Comment: I've seen this same behavior myself... looking forward for the answer :)

Comment: You need to understand the difference between object **properties** and element **attributes**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: @haim770 the link shed some light thanks

Comment: Posted part of that answer so this question also gets answered. Thank you @haim770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

> The value property reflects the current text-content inside the input box, whereas the value attribute contains the initial text-content of the value attribute from the HTML source code.
>
> So if you want to know what's currently inside the text-box, read the property. If you, however, want to know what the initial value of the text-box was, read the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML value attribute isn’t necessarily the value that is displayed on the page. It is known as the default value – used when the page is first loaded

You have to set the `defaultValue`.

Try:

```
var formElement = document.createElement('input');
formElement.type = 'text';
formElement.defaultValue = "test";
formElement.name="test2";
console.log(formElement);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NbsBE/)